# How does a web browser know which protocol to use, when contacting a server for the first time?

Tags: browser, internet-connection

I'm wondering, with Google servers being able to communicate over QUIC instead of TCP, how does the web browser know, that this is possible?

Does it first start a normal TCP connection and the server informs the browser about its capabilities, or does the DNS request has information about it?

Comment: I don't yet know enough to write an answer, but start with https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7838 and https://github.com/quicwg/base-drafts/issues/253

Answer (score 0):

I talked to someone on the #firefox IRC channel, who confirmed, that QUIC uses [Alt-Svc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7838) headers.

These headers can be sent by the server in any HTTP response and point to an alternative way to get a particular resource. This can mean a different URL, a different port or even a different protocol, in this case QUIC.

So there must be an initial TCP/HTTPS connection to the server, before the browser can remember to start a QUIC connection from the get go.